# Correct way to use getopt/long_getopt

Tags: c++, unix, command-line, command-line-arguments, getopt

I know this topic has been beaten to death but I still couldn't find what I am searching for.
I need to parse command line arguments in C++.

I cannot use Boost and using long_getopt

The issue is in casting, when I simply print the arguments , it works as expected in the loop but the value assigned to variables is not working somehow.

Here is the complete , compilable program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <getopt.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    int iterations = 0;
    float decay = 0.0f;
    int option_index = 0;
    static struct option long_options[] =
    {
        {"decay",  required_argument, 0, 'd'},
        {"iteration_num",  required_argument, 0, 'i'},
        {0, 0, 0, 0}
    };

    while ((c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "d:i:",
                long_options, &option_index)  ) !=-1)
     {
        /* getopt_long stores the option index here. */

        switch (c)
        {
        case 'i':
        //I think issue is here, but how do I typecast properly? 
        // especially when my other argument will be a float 
        iterations  = static_cast<int>(*optarg);    
        cout<<endl<<"option -i value "<< optarg;
        break;

        case 'd':
        decay = static_cast<float>(*optarg);
        cout<<endl<<"option -d with value "<<optarg;
        break;

     }
    }//end while
    cout << endl<<"Value from variables, which is different/not-expected";
    cout << endl<< decay << endl << iterations <<  endl;
return(0);
}
```

As I mentioned in the comment - think the problem is in typecasting, how to do it properly? If there is any other way which is better, please do let me know.

You can run the program as --- ./program-name -d .8 -i 100

Thank you for your help. I am new to Unix and C++ but trying very hard to learn it :)

Comment: getopt and friends are (pretty much) obsolete and have been replaced with argp_parse().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are casting a string (char*) value to integer values, which is very different from parsing it. By casting, you use the ASCII value of the first character as a numerical value, while by parsing a string, you try to interpret the whole string as a text and convert it into a machine-readable value format.

You need to use a parsing function like:

```
std::stringstream argument(optarg);
argument >> iterations;
```

or

```
boost::lexical_cast<int>(optarg);
```

or (C-style)

```
atoi(optarg)
```

Comment: +1, except for one aspect.  This cast does not "reinterpret the bytes"; it simply converts the value of the first `char` to the equivalent `int`.  (This is very different to e.g. `*(reinterpret_cast<int *>(optarg))`.)

Comment: @thiton,thanks, I tried your first suggestion but I get the error - invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘std::_Ios_Openmode’ I included the necessary files - fstream and iostream

Comment: You need to include <sstream> and might need to build a std::string from optarg like "std::stringstream argument(std::string(optarg));
"

Comment: @thiton, thanks. That fixed it. I totally forgot about stringstream. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Because optarg is char*. It's plain text. So if you give your program .8 as argument then optarg is a string ".8" and casting it to float doesn't work. Use for example atoi and atof funcions (declared in 'stdlib.h') to parse string as int and float. In your code it would be:

```
iterations = atoi(optarg);
decay = atof(optarg);
```

Comment: I come from C background so do not know much about C++, but isn't this type of cast frowned upon in C++? My point is not to "make it work" but do it elegantly and perfectly.Thanks for helping